# Validation for generated JAXB Classes (JSR 303 / Spring)

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I Generated domain objects from schema (request & response) using JAXB (maven-jaxb2-plugin)
I would like add validations (notnull /empty) for couple of attributes. I would like to have custom Bean Validation, the application is a REST service, i'm using Spring 3 and JSR 303
but i dont think i can use JSR 303 to validate the object as it is generated from the schema.

can someone give me a nudge in the right direction on how to get this done.

Comment: do you mean you that your classes are auto generated from the jaxb schema, that why you can't add the annotation for JSR-303?

Answer (score 4):

We've been using the [Krasa JAXB plugin](https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools) to generate JSR 303-annotated model beans from XSD files, and then [telling Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-triggering) to automatically validate the input beans. This results in very nice, very terse, very DRY code if you have good XSDs.

Answer (score 3):

You can, indeed, do this, via jsr-303 xml configuration.  See, for example, http://www.aviyehuda.com/2010/04/using-hibernate-validator-to-cover-your-validation-needs/.

Answer (score 0):

For NotNull/Empty validation you can use jaxb restriction in schema

here is an example:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="NotEmptyString">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:minLength  value="1"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Or you can use regular expression patterns:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DirType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:pattern value="[LR]*"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

**Note**: the simple type doesn't warrant a class definition of its own. Java's own java.lang.String is used, and the length restriction isn't checked unless you request it via *setEventHandler()* .

more info http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_3_3-Validation.html#Validation

Comment: but how can I get the generated java classes to validate this or to expose minLength=1 so that I can use it elsewhere in the code to trim a string?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path to generate the JAXB. [Click Here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator) to see How JSR 303 Works with POC