# how to validate not null elements using with schemaValidation in JAX-WS/JAXB

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

I am implementing java-first web services using JAX-WS and trying to use the `@SchemaValidation` to validate required elements that are in my webMethod parameters.
here is how I declare my required attribute;

`@XmlElement(required=true)` maps my wsdl schema perfectly(minOccur is not 0 anymore) but the schemaValidation in not validating the passed null elements.

```
@XmlElement(required=true, nillable=false)
public String getClubName() {
    return clubName;
}
```

Any client that uses my API can pass null elements. I don't have a way to prevent this using JAXB.

On the other hand bean validation is working as follows. However not for String fields

```
@Column(name = "FOUNDATION_YEAR", nullable = false) 
private Integer foundationYear;   //schemaValidation validates

@Column(name = "CLUB_NAME", length=100, nullable = false)
private String clubName;    //schemaValidation does not validate
```

How can I use schemaValidation to validate string values? One way is to put restrictions but you can not do that when using java-first web services

```
<xsd:simpleType name="NotEmptyString">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:minLength  value="1"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

related posts;

[Validation for generated JAXB Classes (JSR 303 / Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838133/validation-for-generated-jaxb-classes-jsr-303-spring)

[How to enable schema validation so that JAXB rejects empty element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006103/how-to-enable-schema-validation-so-that-jaxb-rejects-empty-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can do it using JAXB like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089089/framework-to-validate-xml-order-against-xsd). Or maybe use the Schema Validation Framework as described [here](http://myarch.com/using-xml-validation-framework-with-web-services/). But, IMHO, both the approaches add too much clutter to the code, so I'd go for [Guava's Preconditions](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained), which gives you a fast and clean way of doing this. Too bad there's no automatic support for this =/.