# Framework to validate XML order against XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am looking for a Java framework which can validate order of elements in XML against XSD. I have already tried JDK 5's javax.xml.Validate and popular article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html
But none of it gave me specific result.These implementation one way or another told me that xml is invalid but could not provide me specific error description.

Comment: have you tried JAXB 2.0?

Comment: I have just started with JAXB 2.0 with the help of link provided my @MichaBa.

Comment: go ahead its one of the good way to validate and you will be able to get information about validation error.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Do you know how to get the JAXBContext in my case as I don not have any class out of XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe take a look at this page: 
https://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips-100042/175-java-architecture-for-xml-binding/1833-what-is-new-in-jaxb-20.html

You can do nearly everything in XML with the JAXB

Comment: JAXB is the way to go with XML and Java